# mysql find pairs with conditions for each of them

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this :
[image: table1]

I want to find all cids from table1 that this cid has purchase a pid twice. For example in table1, the result should be (3,2) because cid 3 has purchased pid 2 twice.

How can I write a sql to perform that?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cid
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY cid
HAVING COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT pid) > 0
```

**Explanation:**

This query will identify `cid` groups which have a `pid` value appearing twice or more, for at least one `pid` value.  The logic in the `HAVING` clause is that if all `pid` are unique for a `cid` group, then the expression will equal zero, otherwise it will be greater than zero.

Comment: should be `COUNT(distinct pid) > 1`

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, I think the OP did a bad job of wording the requirement.  I updated my query to handle what I think is the actual need.

Comment: thx for reply, I think SELECT cid, pid FROM purchase GROUP BY cid, pid HAVING COUNT(pid) = 2 is enough

Comment: @TomDawn Careful: that query will select any `cid` group which merely has two rows.  You want any `cid` group which has a duplicate `pid` value occurring one or more times.

Comment: but I think its correct, I am grouping by cid,pid pair, and choose only the pair that has count(pid)=2. I have done test on my pc here, it works well for the test cases in above picture

Comment: @TomDawn I originally had that query but I received negative feedback.  Yes, this should work assuming you want to get back the `(cid, pid)` pairs themselves.

Comment: Tim, my comment is solely based on what OP has explained ans yes it's totally unclear and thus I refrained from answering it. None your fault though. Anyways, OP has found it good and accepted the answer and so it ends the story.